# How to use d3.js graphs in Ext.js?

Tags: extjs, d3.js

Can anyone point me to even the simplest example of how to embed d3.js graphics into ext.js?  I've done a lot of searching: I'm not even sure it's possible.  Or is it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

An overly simplified version of what I have used with OK results so far:

```
Ext.define('desktop.controls.d3svg', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.d3svg',

listeners: {

    added: function() {

        this.onAdded();

    }

},

onAdded: function() {

    // ext container has the outer and inner containers
    // use id for selection of inner container for appending svg
    var svg = d3.select('#' + this.id + '-innerCt').append("svg");

    this.svg = svg;

},

onResize: function(width, height) {

    // on the way to an example of using ext resize event and width
    // and height vars
    // this.svg.do_d3_resize_things.....

}

});
```