# Charts D3js + Extjs panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js

I'm trying integrate d3js chart inside a ext panel but with no success... and be able to resize the panel, etc.

The d3js chart render to body and im trying to use html property of ext.panel to call it from body.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Tiago

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948593/how-to-use-d3-js-graphs-in-ext-js) may help.

Comment: Thanks, i check it and post some question on that example. This is my attempt to use extjs with d3 but with no success :( jsfiddle.net/4UrH2/1/

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this question is still relevant for you, but here's a fiddle which demonstrates a simple bar chart inside ExtJS panel `-` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kendopunk/CqCDU/)